# Symfony Sonata project: Input text collection JavaScript issue

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am trying to add collection of input texts with add/delete buttons on admin block.

The problem is when I hit add button I get new 3 or 4 or even 5 new input fields instead of one!

The js function `setup_collection_buttons` called more than once hence attached more click events on HTML element `.sonata-collection-add`

**Before** clicking:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug. I filed issue against AdminBundle

[Issue on github](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3533)